# Always show bottom tab navigators React Navigation 5 in React Naive

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator, react-navigation-bottom-tab

[image]Make a fix bottom tab navigator appear, even if I click on the stack navigator or multiple nested stack navigators it still show the bottom tab navigation like the Facebook app. Like below of this example, I click in page, which is nested stack navigation but the bottom tab navigator still always appear. Generally when I click on stack navigator new screen will be on top and bottom tab navigator will be disappear.

Comment: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hiding-tabbar-in-screens. I'm 100% sure that you need a rethink like in the link mention. It happen to me. If you need help paste your stack code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can use nested react navigation 5, reference document: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/

Answer (score 0):

Besides hiding the tab navigator from props etc, you need to consider your navigator placement. Parent navigator's UI will always rendered on top of the child navigator UI. This is from react navigation [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/#parent-navigators-ui-is-rendered-on-top-of-child-navigator):

> Stack navigators nested inside each screen of tab navigator - **The tab bar is always visible**. Usually pressing the tab again also pops the stack to top.